# realizar un sorteo de 5 temas

Tags: java, clase

Tengo que realizar un programa de un sorteo, en el que tengan que salir 5 temas. He generado un arraylist con todos los temas que he importado desde un fichero y un metodo para obtener 5 numeros aleatorios. Quiero saber es lo que tengo que hacer para que me salgan los temas del arraylist que estén vinculados con esos números aleatorios.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //definimos una lista para los temas que vayamos a cargar de nuestro fichero
        ArrayList<Tema> ArrayListInfromatica = new ArrayList<Tema>();
        //OBTENER EL FICHERO MEDIANTE SU RUTA
        File fichero = new File("D:\\temas_informatica.txt");
        Scanner s= null;
        try{
           System.out.println("leer el contenido del fichero...");
            s = new Scanner(fichero, "UTF-8");
            while(s.hasNextLine()){
                String registro = s.nextLine();
                String [] cortarString = registro.split("::");
                
                Tema temas_informatica = new Tema();
                temas_informatica.setNumeroTema(Integer.parseInt(cortarString[0]));
                temas_informatica.setNombreTema(cortarString[1]);
                //añadir el objeto al Arraylist
                ArrayListInfromatica.add(temas_informatica);
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NumberFormatException e3){
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if(s!=null)
                    s.close();
            }catch(Exception e4){
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Este es el método para generar números aleatorios que hice mediante un array en la clase Tema `int[] numerosAleatorios = new int[5];`

```java
        public int ObtenerNumAleatorio(){
        int numeros_salidos = 0;
        int contador=0;
        boolean equal;
        numerosAleatorios[0]=(int) (Math.random()*75)+1;
        for(int i=0; i<numerosAleatorios.length; i++){
            equal=false;
            numeros_salidos = (int) (Math.random()*75)+1;
            for(int j=0; j<numerosAleatorios.length; j++){
                if(numerosAleatorios[j]==numeros_salidos){
                    equal=true;
                }
            }
            if(equal==false){
            numerosAleatorios[contador] = numeros_salidos;
            contador++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<numerosAleatorios.length; i++){
            System.out.println(numerosAleatorios[i]);
        }
        return numeros_salidos;
```

Answer (score 1):

Una de las formas a implementar es `HashMap` para que vincules una `clave` a un objeto, en tu caso `Tema`.

Esta estructura es formada de la siguiente forma `HashMap<k,v>` donde `k` implica la clave con la cual va a ser creada y `v` el valor(objeto) asignado. Por ejemplo supongamos que la clase `Tema` tiene un `id, nombre`.

Tendríamos:

```java
HashMap<Integer, Tema> list = new HashMap<>();
Tema opcion1 = new Tema(4, "Tema1");
Tema opcion2 = new Tema(6, "Tema2");
list.put(22, opcion1);
list.put(79, opcion2);
```

Nota que la que la `key` con la que ingresas no tiene nada que ver con el objeto ingresado, sin embargo por lo general están ligados puesto que se va acceder a la lista por este.

Para obtener el valor del objeto usamos la `key`

```java
System.out.println( list.get(79) ); //imprime opcion2
```

Ahora bien en tu caso el `key` que ingresas puedes ingresarlo desde tus números aleatorios y así solo recorres tu array con números aleatorios y obtienes el objeto de la lista `HashMap`.

En tu caso:

```java
for(Integer num: numerosAleatorios)
   System.out.println( list.get(num) );
```

*Importante* no te recomiendo usar ArrayList para este caso puesto que debes implementar la comparación al campo que deseas buscar lo que implica sobre escribir el método `equals`.

Comment: Habría manera de hacerlo sin tener que cambiar nada?

Comment: Si, en tu código simplemente cambia `System.out.println(numerosAleatorios[i])` por `ArrayListInfromatica.get(i)` y ya tienes tu tema aleatorio (suponiendo que `i` nunca valga más que la cantidad de temas que tienes, claro. No hay necesidad de utilizar un hashmap solo para sacar un valor aleatorio de un array... cualquier colección te vale para eso!

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me los imprime pero no me salen los 5 temas en si Me sale esto: conexion_fichero.progrma_sorteo.Tema@7c3df479
conexion_fichero.progrma_sorteo.Tema@7106e68e
conexion_fichero.progrma_sorteo.Tema@7eda2dbb
conexion_fichero.progrma_sorteo.Tema@6576fe71
conexion_fichero.progrma_sorteo.Tema@76fb509a

Comment: Falta agregar el método toString() a la clase Tema por eso se muestra así.

Comment: me salen pero no aleatoriamente Tema{numerosAleatorios=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], numeroTema=1, nombreTema=Representación y comunicación de la información.
Tema{numerosAleatorios=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], numeroTema=2, nombreTema=Elementos funcionales de un ordenador digital.
Tema{numerosAleatorios=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], numeroTema=3, nombreTema=Componentes, estructura y funcionamiento de la Unidad Central de Proceso.
.........................Supongo que es porque no me genera bien los numeros aleatorios del array

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me a salido. Cambiando-->                                             `for(int i=0; i<numerosAleatorios.length; i++) {System.out.println(ArrayListInfromatica.get(numerosAleatorios[i]));
 }`